# Debian: Changing keyboard layout doesn't update key positions for game input

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, kde, input-device, wayland

Debian 12 with KDE Plasma 5.27.5, KDE Frameworks 5.103.0, Qt 5.15.8, running Wayland.

In daily work I use a customized version of the Workman layout. I've noticed that changing the layout also affected the location of shortcuts (most notably Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V), which is fine, but for games, this also affects the location of controls (e.g. WASD). For most games, this isn't a problem as I can just remap them to DASH, but some don't have that option and I'm forced to play with a slightly awkward position of movement keys. Most notably, Switchball HD running with Steam Proton.

I tried adding the regular QWERTY layout and switching to it before turning on the game; no luck, the keys are still in different locations. I'm thinking of a workaround involving a keyboard-to-controller mapping program to emulate gamepad inputs with the arrow keys for example (playing Switchball on a controller is pain), but my question is: Why do programs still "think" I'm using the Workman layout even after switching to QWERTY with the taskbar switching tool? Do I need to restart the system after each change, or maybe use some command-line tool to refresh the key locations?